# Is this sporeborn homebrew race balanced compared to other races?

Tags: dnd-5e, balance, homebrew-review, races

It's basically a spore-infested nature-related horrific kind of being, a regular individual of pretty much any race that got infested and biologically changed, linking themselves with nature in the process (unwillingly), while also altering their perception because of being able to feel around their spores.

(Sorry for the terrible English; I had to translate this whole thing.)

> ### Sporeborn
>
> ***Age.*** After being infested, they tend live for up to 40 more years, though that varies based on the original host.
>
> ***Height.*** Depends on the original being.
>
> ***Attributes.*** +1 to Con and +2 to Wis.
>
> ***Alignment.*** Because of their state, and after being rejected by the rest of society, sporeborn will keep to themselves and either attempt, aimlessly, to find a cure for their condition, or wreak havoc amongst the mortal races in anger for their hopelessness, although some may find peace in their contact with nature.
>
> ***Speed.*** 30 feet.
>
> ***Languages.*** Common and one belonging to their original self.
>
> ***Fey.*** You are considered a fey, and gain proficiency in Nature.
>
> ***Blend In.*** Sporeborn have advantage in Stealth checks while out in dense forests.
>
> ***Photosynthesis.*** You gain an additional hit dice to invest while having a short rest if you're receiving direct sunlight during it. This hit dice will be invested before your other ones. This ability works only once per long rest.
>
> ***Spore Cloud.*** After being reduced to 0 hit points, a sporeborn will release a dense cloud of spores in a 20-ft. radius, passing through penetrable obstacles, poisoning all creatures in its reach in a failed Con save. Uses Wis.
>
> ***Natural.*** Sporeborn can cast the spell *speak with plants* once per short rest. After level 10, they can use this ability freely, without delay.
>
> ***Regurgitate.*** You can expel spores through your mouth, hitting up to two other creatures in a 15-ft. radius around you, poisoning them on a failed Con save for a turn. Alternatively, you may focus on your spores on one creature, making them gag for a turn on a failed Dex save, causing the same effects as *silence* for its duration. This ability may be silenced. You use Wis for this ability. Recharges upon short rest.
>
> ***Flammable.*** You are vulnerable to fire.
>
> ***Monstrous.*** You are considered a terrible, detestable being by common folk, and must cover your body and smell to evade conflicts.

I'm new to this, and I don't really know what to do. Also, yeah, they are fey, but for reasons related to my campaign's lore.

Comment: 1. Welcome aboard! Glad to have you here. Make sure you check out our [tour] and feel free to visit [chat] after you get enough rep.

Comment: 2. Is Spore Cloud saying that the DC is 8 + proficiency + Wisdom?

Comment: Yeah, sorry for not specifying

Comment: "Poisoned" As in the original condition, yes, which makes a creature have disadvantage on attack rolls and hability checks. They are not immune to poison, altough, as their body is only resistant to its own spores, not to outside toxins.

Comment: but they are immune to their own ability here, okay. what about others of the same race?

Comment: they'd be immune as well, indeed

Comment: and out of curiosity, are all of the PCs going to be sporeborn?

Comment: They have not yet decided. Are you suggesting they may want to abuse spore cloud? It would be quite weird, as they would need to, well, "die", in order to do that. I'd imagine i could make the spore clouds themselves be flammable, if that was the case? Though that would make helping the fallen sporeborn very difficult.

Comment: I'm a DM creating content for a campaign.

Comment: The concern, as mentioned by nobody, is that if a sporeborn and a half orc are fighting side by side and the sporeborn goes down, suddenly it's a potential issue.

Comment: Out of curiosity - Translated from what - the English was all good.

Comment: You could make the Photosynthesis effect a lot simpler by saying something like "When you spend at least one hit die at the end of a short rest which you spent exposing your body to direct sunlight, you regain additional hit points equal to 1d8 plus your constitution modifier. Once you have used this feature, you cannot use it again until you take a long rest." (Free hit dice are weird because you could be a multiclass character with two different hit die sizes and it gets into "which die do I use?"  Look at the bard's song of rest for an example.)

Comment: I had to translate all of those rules (and quite in a hurry, too) so it sounds kinda incohesive, but it makes a lot more sense in the original language.

Comment: and having it be a fixed dice value is a good idea, i agree.

Answer (score 11):

### The biggest problem is that this is near unplayable in a group

Player races are meant to be played as player characters, and in D&D 5e, the assumption is that you adventure in a group of such characters. Drop

> **Alignment**. Because of their state, and after being rejected by the rest of society, sporeborn will keep to themselves and either attempt, aimlessly, to find a cure for their condition, or wreak havoc amongst the mortal races in anger for their hopelessness, although some may find peace in their contact with nature.

This is entirely antisocial, and a non-starter for a game that assumes the character will be part of a mixed group. At least, unless all of them are sporeborn, and that is an unpractical assumption to make for a game where each player typically decides what character they want to play. Just drop this.

**Monstrous**.  You are considered a terrible, detestable being by common folk, and must cover your body and smell to evade conflicts.

This likewise makes the race very hard to play in any normal campaign, where common folk are the backdrop of play, when you visit villages, towns and cities. Drow characters have had issus with this in past editions (when practially all drow were irrevocably evil). There are no straightforward ways to cover "smell", and the race has no feature to disguise itself. I'd remove the smell aspect, at least.

#### Power assessment

I will also take a look at the power level, and make some suggestions, using [detect balance](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/200314/what-is-detect-balance) to try and get that race to a level that is in line with other races. One common trap that you fell into is making maybe too many special features, compared to typcial published races.

You should sum up to 25 points or so, and you already have 12 from the ability score increases. **Height, age, speed** and **languages** are standard and add or subtract nothing.

**Fey**: Clarify the language to "Intelligence (Nature)", if that is what you mean. Non-humanoid is +2, a skill is +2, total +4.

**Blend In**. Stealth is one of the most often used skills (based on [statisitics the Critical Role team made](https://www.reddit.com/r/DnD/comments/pwnwpu/what_skills_are_called_for_most_a_critical_role/)), only a little behind the #1 skill perception, but here is limited to only within dense forests. Advantage on a situational roll is worth +2.

**Flammable**: drop this. Vulnerabilty is extremely hard to balance, because it just can spell death when being hit by a fireball or something like that, which normally would not be so deadly. Instead of using vulnerabilty to balance overtly strong other features, mellow down those other features. It would give you -20 points more to play with, but it [really is a bad idea](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/202893/create-the-most-broken-race-that-is-balanced-according-to-detect-balance).

**Spore Cloud**: This needs to specify a DC, use language copying the published features, to be clear. You confirm in a comment the DC is 8 + Proficiency + Wisdom Ability Bonus, this should be in the text. It also should state that this causes the *poisoned* condition (again, clarified in comments), as there are many other kinds of poisons. The ability will also affect the rest of the characters, so has quite some risk to contribute to a TPK, as it might poison the whole team at a time when you already are down. It also does not state a duration. You could at least limit it to 1 round, to make it more bearable. This one is hard to score as it is as much a liabiltiy as a power, probably more so, unless the whole team is immune to poison (like with *heroes feast*). I'll put it at +0, and would recommend to cut this feature. You already get to spew spores with the Regurgitate one, so it is really a bit superfluous.

**Immunity to poison**: You added in comments the race also would be immune to poison, but this is not in the race description. Even simple resistance to poison is already +4 points, so immunity would be more than +8, but none of the published races has an immunity. You do not need this, so I would leave it off. If you use it, make it resistance at best. I'll assume you leave it off, for +0.

**Photosynthesis**: There is no limit on the hit dice you can take in a short rest. If what you mean is that you get one extra hit die to spend, in addition to your other hit dice, in most cases this is depending on your hit die and Con bonus worth between +d6-1 hp or +d12+5 hp. The average is likely somewhere around d8 or d10 + 2 or 3 hp, similar to a *cure wounds*, with the downside it only works during a rest, and worth about +3 points.

**Natural**: looks OK, it's a lot of free spells per day, and this is a level 3 spell. I would probably drop the level 10 rider, and limit this to once per long rest, starting at 5th level, which is +3 points.

**Regurgitate**. Assuming this uses the same DC as above. This also needs to specify the action cost -- I will assume this takes a full action. I think for consistency, you should really limit this to only the Constitution save, not an option of a Dexterity save instead. This is very strong, as it effectively the ability to give Disadvantge to 2 opponents nearly every fight. (There are typically 3-4 fights per day, so you can take a short rest in most cases in between). The only saving grace is that a lot of monsters have advantage against poison, or are outright immune to it. I think the ability to silence one creature may be too strong, it can entirely invalidate a spellcaster for a turn, and most fights are just 3 or so turns. I'd probably tone this down and reduce the range to 5 or 10 feet so you need to at least get close to that spellcaster, and they often seek protection behind some meatshields. I'd suggest to drop the part of *silence* affecting this, first spewing spores is not making noise, so silence should not affect it, second, it is very rare that PCs get silenced, so it is just rules overhead that needs to be remembered for little play time. A comparator is *ray of sickness*, which also causes the poisoned condition on a failed save for 1 turn, has a range of 60 and is a first level spell that costs an action (it also requires you to hit first). So this is worth *at least* 3-4 times the 3 points a first level spell costs, and this is arguably twice as strong with hitting 2 targets and not needing a to-hit roll, and being able to silence spellcasters, so it probably should be at least level 2. This would be worth far more than 12 points.

At this point, you are already at 12 + 4 + 2 + 3 + 3 = 24 points, so you only really can afford 1 more. Make this a daily power, maybe comparable to a level 2 spell available from 3rd level, which would be 3 points, getting you to 27. That is already on the higher side, and if we misevaluate something, we might be over the top, so you could consider to drop something, either Blend In, or maybe Intelligence (Nature) or another of the +2 or +3 features, depending on what is most important to you.

Comment: You forgot to comment about "blend in" which i would guess is quite a great situational advantage? Being so situational, and considering that my campaigns have many different biomes, i suppose it's worth keeping. Sounds like fun roleplay, too.

Comment: Ah sorry, yes I missed that one ... so many features. I will add it in.

Comment: Alright, much appreciated! Thank you for the help, it really opened my eyes.
The end race now has regurgitate (only one target, poisoned for a turn), blend in (useful and ocasionally funny), photosynteshis (ocasionally helpful, basically works like a daily cure wounds on self), and natural (speak with plants, once per long rest).
Dropped the fey, as they're technically not it, and the proficiency, as technically they didn't gain any knowledge by turning into a tree monster.

Comment: Dropped spore cloud, too. And the weakness, and the "monstrous" thing.

Comment: Looks you have some references to other editions. Nature is Intelligence in 5e, not Knowledge, and *cure light wounds* is no longer a spell

Comment: @DavidCoffron Thanks for catching these, fixed them.

Comment: This is a great answer, but I would argue that 27 is not really on a higher side for balance when taking into account the newer books. The average Detect Balance for all published races is (if my calculation is correct) ~ 29.5, and the average for races published since Theros is ~ 33

Comment: @Deeps Yes there is some power creep. This is high by the standards of the core rules, and by the guidance from DT, which has not been updated for the newer races. I think there is an updated version that has a slightly adjusted scoring theme, and also recommends a slightly higher average. And 27 would still be in range, the concern is more that there is a risk of misevaluating unique features like here. But I agree, it might be just OK — that's why I did not recommend to drop something, just asked to OP to consider it.

Comment: btw, they said immune to their own poison effect. So, they don't get poisoned when spore cloud or regurgitate happens, which seems good imo

Comment: And interestingly, I'd pegged photosynthesis at +2 instead of +3

Comment: @goodguy5 That's also reasonable - you only can use it during a rest, and cannot heal others with it.

Comment: """near unplayable in a group"""

this feels rather extreme, especially as the text qualifies "some may find peace in their contact with nature". Keeping to themselves doesn't really mean they can't join a party either, esp if they want to find a cure.

Yes, there might be disadvantages but it feels in line with tieflings ("to be greeted with stares and whispers, to suffer violence and insult on the street, to see mistrust and fear in every eye") and drow ("banished from the surface world")

Comment: That's true falsedot. And besides, i have a group of friends i always play with, so there's not a whole lot of chance that someone will isolate themselves just because of the race description. As the race was never meant to be "published" for other people to use, i ended up not even considering the induced level of edginess.

Comment: I think the legacy Yuan-Ti does have poison immunity and it does cost +8 on "detect balance". Though it's not supposed to be balanced for PCs anyways.